# A question on polynomials1

Tags: calculus

Let $\lambda \in (0,1)$ , and $X_\lambda$ is positive root of $$ {\alpha _m}{X^m} +  \cdots  + {\alpha _1}{X^1} - ({\alpha _0} - \lambda ) = 0$$
such that ${\alpha _0},{\alpha _1}, \ldots ,{\alpha _m} \in {\mathbb{R}^ + }$.

(Let ${X_\lambda } =  + \infty $ whenever this equation has no positive roots.)

Can we say that, $X_\lambda$, is  ***decreasing function*** of $\lambda\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Are you sure this question is correctly stated? Clearly $f(x)=a_mx^m+\dots+a_1x$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$ for positive $x$, and $f(0)=0$. So $f(x)=k$ will have a unique positive root for $k>0$ and this root will decrease as we decrease $k$ (or increase $\lambda$). But I can see no reason why the root should not exceed $2$ (say) for all $\lambda\in(0,1)$ if $a_0$ is large. Equally, if $a_0<1$, then $f(x)=a_0-\lambda$ will not have *any* positive roots for $\lambda>a_0$.

Comment: @almagest - Thanks. I edited this post.

Comment: This is still not correct. Do you want $\lambda\in(0,a_0)$ rather than $(0,1)$ (and $\lambda\to a_0$ rather than $\lambda\to 1$)?

Comment: @almagest - No.

Comment: @almagest - In generally, If ${a_m}{X^m} +  \cdots  + {a_1}X - {a_0} = 0$ and ${a_0}, \ldots ,{a_m} > 0$ then this equation has exactly one positive zero.

Comment: That is true, but your result is still either false or meaningless as currently stated.

Comment: @almagest - I edited my question again. Now what?

Comment: Take the polynomial as $x-(2-\lambda)$. This has the root $2-\lambda$. The root decreases as $\lambda$ decreases. But the root does not tend to 0 as $\lambda\to1$.

Comment: @almagest - I edited my question again. Now what?

Comment: Now the result would be true if you changed your value for no positive roots from $\infty$ to $0$. It is also easy to prove as I pointed out in my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $f(x)=a_mx^m+\dots+a_1x$. Since $f(x)$ has all its coefficients positive, it is a strictly increasing function of $x$ for positive $x$. We also have $f(0)=0$, so $f(x)=k$ must have a unique positive solution for each positive $k$.

Moreover, if we call this solution $\beta_k$, we can see that $\beta_k$ increases as $k$ increases (and decreases as $k$ decreases).

In particular if we put $k=a_0-\lambda$, then $\beta_k$ will decrease as $\lambda$ increases.

If $a_0\ge1$, then this means that for *any* $\lambda\in(0,1)$, $f(x)=a_0-\lambda$ will have a positive root, and this root will decrease as $\lambda$ increases.

But if $a_0<1$, then as $\lambda$ increases from $0$ to $a_0$ the positive root will decrease to $0$ and for $a_0\le\lambda<1$ there will be no positive root (because $a_0-\lambda$ will be non-positive, whereas $f(x)$ is positive for all positive $x$).